# Change Data Capture and Transactional Replication Conflict

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication, change-data-capture

When trying to activate the Change Data Capture (CDC) feature, and there is already a Transactional Replication solution running in the SQL Server Instance, a conflict is generated.

We tried stopping the Replication publication agent (through the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) to configure the CDC. However, the job capture isn't getting created automatically. And, when trying to create it manually, the following message appears:

> The capture job cannot be used by Change Data Capture to extract changes from the log when transactional replication is also enabled on the same database. When Change Data Capture and transactional replication are both enabled on a database, use the logreader agent to extract the log changes.

Which corroborates the conflict between these two features.

Thus, if Replication is mandatory and CDC is now trying to be used as well, what alternative could be taken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong - both CDC and replication can use that same log reader and so trying to call `sp_cdc_add_job` to add the log reader when one already exists will result in that error. Said another way, if you already have replication set up, you can skip the step in the CDC setup process that says to add a log reader (because you already have one).

When you configure both CDC and replication on the same database do one or both not function as intended? That is, if you see changes being captured (CDC) and reflected at subscribers (replication), there's nothing to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks! I configured the CDC (without the capture job) and left the Replication active, because as you said, it seems luckily the SQL server instance is being able to manage both CDC and Transactional Replication at the same time using the one log reader it has. Thus, for now there's nothing to troubleshoot since it's handling both features simultaneously; capturing changes and reflecting data to the subscriber.

Comment: Not so much luck but a smart choice by the developers of CDC. They'd have needed some way to consume those changes anyways and saw the extant replication log reader as a convenient way to do that. Why write something new when most of the functionality you need already exists?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add, that the Log Reader Agent runs on the server where the distribution database is located. It can run also on subscriber. In such case, it connects to Publisher machine and runs replication tasks(sp_repl.. procedures) there. Also CDC tasks. This works, but raises performance issues.
It might be better to move the distributor to the publisher machine to run all involved procedures locally.